# Colab VM requested does not exist, despite status claiming it is running and available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-colaboratory, google-compute-engine

I've been having trouble with setting up a Colab VM via Google Compute Engine, despite being able to access it flawlessly earlier. I have tried starting and stopping the VM, as well as deploying a fully new VM. Neither seems to fix the issue that Colab seems unwilling to recognize its existence. Neither following the Google "Connect to VM with Colab" button in the GCE deployment manager, or manually inputting the VM allow it to connect (yes, I did triple check that everything was spelled correctly when manually inputting).

Following the advice listed [here,](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2880) I attempted to manually reset the docker, though it still reports to be up and running with no issues (although unreachable). Upon requesting the status with `sudo systemctl status k_default`, I received the following status report:

```
k_default.service - kernel default docker container
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/k_default.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-09-21 05:12:06 UTC; 1min 23s ago
    Process: 1006 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker-credential-gcr configure-docker --include-artifact-registry (co>
    Process: 1012 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /tmp/var-colab && touch /tmp/var-colab/mp (code=exited, s>
   Main PID: 1014 (docker)
      Tasks: 9 (limit: 36104)
     Memory: 13.4M
        CPU: 53ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/k_default.service
             └─1014 docker run -e COLAB_JUPYTER_TOKEN= -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 --name k_default --privileged -->

Sep 21 05:12:16 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:16.979Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: Writing note>
Sep 21 05:12:16 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:16.980Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: Authenticati>
Sep 21 05:12:17 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:17.026Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: google.colab>
Sep 21 05:12:17 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: 2023-09-21 05:12:17.122726: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_gu>
Sep 21 05:12:17 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, >
Sep 21 05:12:19 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:19.591Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: Serving note>
Sep 21 05:12:19 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:19.591Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: Jupyter Note>
Sep 21 05:12:19 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:19.591Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: http://127.0>
Sep 21 05:12:19 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: [2023-09-21T05:12:19.592Z]  INFO: app/1 on 2aacc05ca29f: Use Control->
Sep 21 05:12:19 colab-1-vm docker[1014]: 2023-09-21 05:12:19.820506: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/p>
```

Any advice to get this up and running would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!